# C# .Net Close application on exceeding memory usage

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application which deals with huge amount of in-memory data. Now, sometimes what happens is that memory limit of 2GB/app is reached and my program hangs. The memory usage in the task manager goes haywire (continuously fluctuates from 2GB to 6GB)
What I want is that when the memory usage reaches a particular limit, the program should gracefully exit. I don't want manual intervention of user killing the app. Is this possible?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to re-write the app to not use up all of the available memory and/or track down the memory leak (if it's not using all of the memory by design)?

Comment: Have you thought how the user would feel that in midst of something it pops out a message "Sorry memory threshold hit ..gotta go", he would be banging his head :(

Comment: How huge data you are talking about? Dealing with terrabytes of data can also be managed with proper coding and design. I think you should try to refine your application. I will be happy to to know more about your application does...

Comment: Actually, there is no issue of any memory leak. The memory use is by design. And I can't know how much memory the program would need. It depends on the size of the DB table.

Comment: _"It depends on the size of the DB table"_ - do you need all data in memory at all times?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. I have an xml which is created by my program in memory. The data comes from the DB. I need to manipulate the xml data before creating the xml file hence I don't want to use XMLReader/XMLWriter. I have to contend with  in memory API's like XDocument

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should allocate a background monitoring thread, which polls System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64 and then acts accordingly to the size returned.

Eg.

```
public class MonitoringThread : Thread{
...

bool working = true;
void run(){
   while(working){
      long size = Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64;
      if (size > 2000000000){
         //do anything
      }
      else {
         try{
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
         }
         catch{}
      }
   }
}

}
```

Please note that I just wrote this code in this page, so it may be not too accurate :)

Comment: You should call `Process.Refresh();` before asking for the current commit memory size - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.refresh.aspx.

Comment: No, I didn't store a reference of Process exactly for this reason: calling each time "Process.GetCurrentProcess()" does take a new process snapshot without caching it.

Comment: You are right, I had assumed that `Process.GetCurrentProcess()` caches a reference to the current process, but it creates a new object every time.

Comment: I think that both the solutions are correct and equivalent: simply I didn't see the need to allocate a object which then i have to refresh, overwriting it. :)

Comment: Thanks @LittleSweetSeas Seems to be a good enough solution. Still I want to try it before marking this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Garbage Collection Notifications`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713687.aspx) to be alerted when a full Garbage Collection has completed.

In response to that, you could check [`GC.GetTotalMemory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory.aspx) to see how much memory is currently used, and take the appropriate action if it is too high.