# How to run a C# program with virtual memory usage constraints

Tags: c#, memory-management, out-of-memory, virtual-memory

Basically I have a **C#** program and while running it I would like to specify the maximum amount of memory it can access. If at any point of the execution, my application crosses the threshold, I would like to terminate it with appropriate exception. The memory constraint can be as low as 100Mb.

I have seen the question [.Net close application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483285/c-sharp-net-close-application-on-exceeding-memory-usage), but the answer there was to check for the `PrivateMemorySize` iteratively. But my program is large and there are many locations at which the memory can cross the threshold.

My idea is that in visual studio, resource monitor keeps track of the memory usage somehow and all I need is a threshold and a flag to kill the application.

Also this feat is achieved in `nodejs` using `set NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=value`

Comment: You could dockerize your application.  Then [you could set the containers max memory](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#limit-a-containers-access-to-memory)

Comment: Pretty important to understand the distinction between virtual memory and RAM.  You only ever allocate virtual memory, it is up to the OS to find RAM for it.  And it takes RAM away just as easily when some is needed for another process.  You can assign the Process.GetCurrentProcess().MaxWorkingSet property but the only thing that does is make your program slower.

Comment: which means you want to make the Virtual memory size = 100MB?

Comment: Slowing down my application is the last thing I want.

Comment: Yes, its the virtual memory.

Comment: Without Docker containers, Win32 [job objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms684161.aspx) are another option, but they have no native managed support, so some P/Invoking would be required. Docker containers have much better tooling.

Comment: _"My idea is that in visual studio, resource monitor keeps track of the memory usage"_ - but you are not running your app out of VS in production, are you?

Answer (score 0):

One work around I found was to package my application and the run it on a linux machine with `mono` installed and with help of `ulimit`, I can easily set the virtual memory limit.

For instance, I can do something like,

`ulimit -v 200000; mono myapplication.exe`

The value set is in **KB**